# Displaying a 3 Dimensional Matrix in OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, opencv

How can I flatten a 3D Matrix and display it in 2d?
Are there simple ways to display it in 3d?

Edit:

So far I simply tile the images in the 3rd dimension together like thus:

```
void Flatten3DArray(const cv::Mat& In, cv::Mat& Out2d)
{
    CV_Assert(In.dims == 3);

    int rows = In.size[0];
    int cols = In.size[1];
    int third = In.size[2];


    int rowTiles = ceil(sqrt(third));
    int colTiles = ceil(sqrt(third));

    Out2d.create(rowTiles*rows, colTiles*cols, In.type());
    Out2d = Scalar(0);

    int thirdDimIdx = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < rowTiles; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < colTiles; ++j, ++thirdDimIdx)
        {

            if (thirdDimIdx >= third)
            {
                break;
            }

            Mat roi(Out2d(cv::Rect(j*cols, i*rows, cols, rows)));

            uint16_t *ind = (uint16_t*)In.data + thirdDimIdx * rows*cols; // sub-matrix pointer
            cv::Mat subMatrix(2, In.size, In.type(), ind);

            subMatrix.copyTo(roi);
        }
    }

}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: "display it in 2d" vs "display it in 3d" - pick one!

Comment: I want to see all levels at the same time

Comment: You want to print it to a console?

Comment: No I use ImageWatch to view it. Though this detail is not important. I could use imshow or imwrite to display it by other means

Comment: Please understand that OpenCV is a 2D processing library and its display capabilities are in the same space as well. That being said, perhaps you could try to integrate this via VTK and display the full 3D image there. VTK will have more options of displaying a 3D mesh.